# Why can Record<string, any> equal Functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object

I was testing various typescript types till I came upon the following situation.

Why can `Record<string, any>` equal Functions?

```
type C = { [key: string]: any } // Record<string, any>;
const C0: C = undefined // error
const C1: C = null // error
const C2: C = 2 // error
const C3: C = 'hello world' // error
const C4: C = { foo: 'bar' } // ok
const C5: C = () => undefined // ok
```

Yet `Records<string, unknown>` can't?

```
type B = { [key: string]: unknown } // Record<string, unknown>;
const B0: B = undefined // error
const B1: B = null // error
const B2: B = 2 // error
const B3: B = 'hello world' // error
const B4: B = { foo: 'bar' } // ok
const B5: B = () => undefined // error
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=15&ssc=39&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBfA3AKAMYHsB2AzsLAAwBcsCUArngCYQBmAlnhHVAPSdQQBOfHH2z4isAIwU4iPNQA2crj36DhuQsRgAmKVS1KoOANYiNsAMy7EAcgAWEBTigB3IXLrWDx02JgAWK2QoRhwcCmsAIwBDPk8ULxN1XwBWQIAKAEoEAD4aeiZWdgSMDFBIKAAhKiQoAG0jCBAKIj5WAHMAXQpaIzwcZzwoeO4oACUIXD46AB4W9oAaPN7%20vGzMJOIK8kqqWgYWNg4RlSEfTckdmXlFY4FTjcqdS6h9W9Uzystnuwc5J1c%20O5PG97qJNgFnjUQmEoJEYnFig8Kqlnpkcnl9oUjso7sJSuBoABhap1BpNKBzPCdChRPAgIYGcaTGaUtqLWkgNYfQnbYmIPYFQ4GE5qMFQQkXPlQWQKYW47lPKWvHHvB6Er5Sn6OFxuDxy1ViwkQqVQ0LhaKxBkjbxqlFStHwXICg5Fa0mfHlAAiVFqHXWYs9229-PyLuxvHlD09F2D0uu%20tBZk9T1jyojBqTX1jWr%20OsBepBoqTENjpphcMtwxVibEnpRsYdTtDWITwiAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Record<string, any>` is special cased for assignability and it basically means any object type. This is explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41746)

> Normally the source type must have an index signature if the target type does, but for : any there's really nothing implied by this (every property must match any, by definition), so we made [s: string]: any a no-op for assignability reasons. This enabled some patterns that didn't work before:

```
function doSomething(obj: { [s: string]: any}) {
  // ...
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
// WAS ERROR: 'obj' lacks index signature
doSomething(obj);
```

> This creates some undesirable assignability in some cases, so we didn't apply this rule to : unknown so that you could pick which behavior you wanted.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying `Function`'s are objects? Or do you imply that `Record<string, any> = any`?

Comment: @SILENT Yes functions are objects. all function signatures extend `Function` which extends `Object` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAFAJQDcAUFPAA4CmMAKtdKjAN6kwwDaYAhotQC44UAE4BLMAHMAukJ5h47Lr35CwAV0RZqI2THmKO3PoLjY8eg0oBuPXOtPRxUpfy06hTiZKUAGITh41PJKnAiIegAiPFDUpAC+pORUtADSYADu4KnU8BAAPHQAfMxsRgAKMBIwANa5IABm9PoQMEocXlIw1AAesWAAJq2VAPwwYNTWOjBC7eOa2iLdfdSDwzBjE1NLsxwd5rjL-UMwo+OT07t75UrSHEJ0nOXSCUkUNDAAGszpWWA5eUKjCgJSAA